# Crawling and parsing Javascript elements

Tags: javascript, web-crawler

I try to get info from a website which uses *Javascript* to show onclick the phonenumber of the items/companies.

Crawling that with PHP curl or xpath did not let me find a solution how to trigger this events and than keep on crawling.

**Example:**

```
<a onclick="show(2423,'../entries.php?eid=2423',1);
```

for info here the function too

```
function show(info_id,qpath,swimage){
expandit(info_id,0,swimage);
if(document.getElementById('load_'+info_id)) {
    ajax_loadContent('cont_td_'+info_id,qpath);
}
 }
```

Is this possible to do with PHP/Xpath/DOM or what do you recommend to do to achieve this?
Any chance for "debugging" the code to see which url to call?

THanks for your concern
And have really great FESTIVITIES

Answer (score 3):

It seems like all it's doing is an AJAX call to this page, `../entries.php?eid=2423`.

Try going to that URL directly and you'll probably get your phone number without any HTML/JavaScript parsing.

Comment: LOL, thanks, you were right. More advanced functions/oursourced might be more difficult to get the info. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the net tab of [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to keep an eye on what URLs are loaded. Or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/). Once you work out the pattern you might be able to craft and call the same URLs yourself using curl.

Or, you could use one of the browser automation frameworks, like [webaii](http://www.artoftest.com/products/webaii.aspx) or [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [watir](http://watir.com/) or [watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) and crawl the links that way.

Comment: which program is best to download the whole page(not just the source code which is shown in the browser) and than process again with dom? it should have all the code, even the not-yet-triggered one like shown in firebug.
Thank you

Comment: This is a good approach, paying attention to what the browser is loading solved my life. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using Selenium RC to simulate clicking on the link and then scan the page for results:
http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/